# Did doctor/journalist Sanjay Gupta perform brain surgery on a wounded soldier in the heat of war?

Tags: war, surgery, mehmet-oz

According to [this recap](http://www.recapo.com/dr-oz/dr-oz-advice/dr-oz-dr-sanjay-gupta-iraq-drill-bit-surgery-monday-mornings-review/) of an interview of [Dr Sanjay Gupta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanjay_Gupta) on the [Dr Oz Show](http://www.doctoroz.com/), there was an incident while he was acting as a journalist in a war zone in Iraq:

> While in Iraq, he encountered a soldier with a critical head wound. He
>   switched roles from reporter to surgeon to offer his expertise, but
>   the field was not prepared for such intensive surgery.
>
> He improvised, using a Black and Decker drill bit to perform brain
>   surgery on a soldier, who was then airlifted out of the danger zone
>   for further treatment.

Given that it is a Dr. Oz show, which makes me incredibly skeptical of anything he says, is there anything to substantiate this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

See [Time.com](http://content.time.com/time/nation/article/0,8599,1870277,00.html). They repeat a quote of his from a CNN article:

> As a neurosurgeon, I was asked to step back from my journalist's role to look at his gunshot wound to the head. Shortly thereafter, I was removing a bullet from his brain.

From [The Salt Lake Tribune](http://www.informationclearinghouse.info/article4469.htm):

> I probably owe my life to Dr. Gupta.

(said by Jesus Vidana, who "learned that the Navy's so-called Devil Docs had asked CNN medical correspondent Sanjay Gupta, a neurosurgeon, to operate when Vidana was airlifted to a field hospital in Iraq").

And from [Los Angeles Daily News](http://www.dailynews.com/20090109/gupta-removed-bullet-from-sun-valley-marines-head):

> Gupta switched from reporter to doctor, grabbed a drill bit and went to work.

Comment: So they were lying when they said "Gupta performed surgery, then they airlifted the soldier out of the danger zone" correct?  It's not like he did the surgery right after he got hit, because your article mentions he operated at a field hospital

Comment: Where does the article say that?

Comment: *said by Jesus Vidana, who "learned that the Navy's so-called Devil Docs had asked CNN medical correspondent Sanjay Gupta, a neurosurgeon, **to operate when Vidana was airlifted to a field hospital in Iraq***

Comment: But the article I cited states: *He improvised, using a Black and Decker drill bit to perform brain surgery on a soldier, who **was then airlifted out of the danger zone** for further treatment.*  Makes the article sounds like they tried to embellish it

Comment: I took that as saying that he learned that Gupta operated. And that that learning happened when vidana was airlifted.

Comment: But the way he says it implied "the neurosurgeon operated AFTER him being airlifted to a hospital", whereas one of your sources states "the neurosurgeon operated on him, THEN he was airlifted to a hospital".

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark Okay.

Comment: http://www.buffalo.edu/ubreporter/campus/campus-host-page.host.html/content/shared/university/news/ub-reporter-articles/stories/2014/March/gupta_dss.detail.html is where Dr Gupta recounts his version of the events

Comment: "he was embedded in Iraq with the Navy’s elite Devil Docs group, which erects sophisticated surgical suites just behind front-line troops; its purpose was to cut the amount of time it took to get medical care to critically injured soldiers."